# Can't get fresh Ubuntu server to update/upgrade

Tags: server, 17.04

I've got a fresh Ubuntu 17.04 server, I've configured networking and can resolve all addresses as I'd expect, however when I run sudo apt update I get to ~19% at which point I get a load of messages indicating failures, such as...

```
err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security release 404 not found  [91.189.88.162 80]
```

and then

```
Repository http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security does not have a release file
```

this is repeated several times.

All the listed URIs are reachable/resolve from terminal.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Fails with

```
 reading package list... done
 building dependency tree
 reading state information... done
 calculating upgrade... done
 0 upgraded, 0 newely installed, 0 to remove and 0 upgraded
```

The problem is that without updates I can't get any other packages to install and I'm not familiar enough with linux to deal with it.
Anyone got any thoughts on why updates aren't taking?

I know I'm supposed to be on 17.10 by now but I was hoping that'd be able to be sorted with an upgrade!

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is EOL (2017.April + 9months = 13-Jan-2018), and sometime post-EOL the repos get moved from `archives.ubuntu.com` (where it looks for updates) to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` - so its looking for updates when they've gone. Given its a clean install - just use 17.10, or an LTS (long term support) version if you don't want to upgrade often.  (the following link [next comment] provides info if you want to upgrade from 17.04)

Comment: If you look at the folders (`http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`); you'll find artful, xenial & other supported releases - but you'll note the 'zesty' folders are gone

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, I knew 17.04 was out of date but I hadn't expected it to be so ruthlessly purged. I'll just build from scratch with a newer version. Much appreciated.

Comment: @guiverc your comment is a valid answer - could you post it as an answer?

Note that even though this is about an EOL release it's specifically about how to upgrade it, so perhaps this is still a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04, released in 2017-April (hence 17.04) came with nine months of support; 2017-04 + 9 months = 13-Jan-2018 EOL (End-Of-Life).

Sometime after EOL (no length-of-time is defined) the repos get moved from `archives.ubuntu.com` (where Ubuntu versions look for updates) to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, so your 17.04 is looking for updates where they were.

Given it's a clean install - just use 17.10, or an LTS (long term support; five years of support) version if you don't want to upgrade often.

If you looked (eg. opened-in-a-browser) the address you specified `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` has artful (17.10), xenial (16.04), trusty (14.04) & other supported releases (inc. 'in-test' 18.04), but will discover the 'zesty' (17.04) & other post-EOL release folders are gone.